# Attempting to move div after file upload

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to move the file upload div to beside the image after uploading. The image uploading works, but I can't move the file upload div to another place besides of the image. It stayed like fix block div without moving div. How can I do that?Please help me.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');
        document.getElementById('previewImg').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}, false);
```

```css
.dialog-circle {
  width: 210px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: rgb(44, 108, 128);
}

#dialog-horizontal-plus {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 19%;
  height: 3%;
  left: 40%;
  top: 42.75%;
}

.dialog-vertical-plus {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 2%;
  height: 20%;
  left: 49%;
  top: 30.5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' id="files" name="image" multiple="multiple" style="display:none" />
<div id='previewImg'></div>
<div class='dialog-circle' style="display:block;" onclick="document.getElementById('files').click()">
  <div id='dialog-horizontal-plus'></div>
  <div id='previewImg' class='dialog-vertical-plus'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you got double `#previewImg`? Also it's duplicate `ID`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a certain `width` for `#previewImg span` then set `float: left` also on `.dialog-circle`

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');
        document.getElementById('previewImg').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}, false);
```

```css
.dialog-circle {
    width: 210px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: rgb(44, 108, 128);
    float: left;
}
#dialog-horizontal-plus {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 19%;
  height: 3%;
  left: 40%;
  top: 42.75%;
}

.dialog-vertical-plus {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 2%;
  height: 20%;
  left: 49%;
  top: 30.5%;
}

#previewImg span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#previewImg span img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' id="files" name="image" multiple="multiple" style="display:none" />

<div class='dialog-circle' style="display:block;" onclick="document.getElementById('files').click()">
  <div id='dialog-horizontal-plus'></div>
  <div class='dialog-vertical-plus'></div>
</div>

<div id='previewImg'></div>
```